# How to access the development database with the Play! framework?

Tags: java, database, playframework, h2

I want to see the tables of my Play! application with the H2 console, but all I see is a list of internal tables of the db engine. How can I view the tables of my application?

[image: H2 Console]

Comment: What are the db.* settings in application.conf?

Comment: The only db config is `db=mem`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Log on to the JDBC URL `jdbc:h2:mem:play` instead. That is where the development database runs on at least on my Play instance.

Comment: I cannot see the tables of my application with the connection string `jdbc:h2:mem:play`.

Comment: In-memory databases (`jdbc:h2:mem:...`) are only visible from within the _same_ process. If you start the H2 Console from another process, then you will open another database.

Comment: The problem was, that I haven't called the application itself (`http://localhost:9000/`) before opening the h2 console (`http://localhost:9000/@db`) so the db schema wasn't built. I'm using the connection string `jdbc:h2:mem:play` and it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely, you are looking a *different* database. Could you verify the database URL is really `jdbc:h2:~/play`?

You should also consider upgrading to a more recent version of H2. The version you are using (1.3.149) is a beta version.

Comment: I'm using that connection string in the log-on dialog, but I cannot see the tables of my application.

Comment: Yes, we know you are using `jdbc:h2:~/play` when you login to the H2 Console. The question is, what database URL do you use in the Play! application. They need to match.